# Web App IoT Hub Data Visualization of just one specific device

Tags: javascript, azure, iot

I am in the middle of the development of an IoT solution.

The product consists of a web site with many users and each user can access the real-time data of just his device/s. While the admin can access to all the devices.

I have followed this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-node-send-v2) for the streaming of the device's data from the IoT hub.

But I do not know how to stream just one device data instead of all devices connected to the IoT hub.

Is there any way where I can specify which device/s I want to start reading from the IoT hub?

Comment: When you say you have a website, how are you planning to feed event stream to that website? I mean what is your design for the data layer? The simplest solution would require a backend service (you can consider Azure Function) to listen from IoT Hub and dump events to your database. Then based on the User-Device mapping, your website can fetch only the events filtering on the logged in user id.

Comment: Hi @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT The web site is very similar to this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-web-apps in Azure documentation 

What I wanted to do instead of reading constantly the data from the db is streaming it directly to the website.

Comment: Yes, the example you are following reads the raw stream directly from IoT Hub. In your case since you need filtering by device, you need to introduce a layer in between. If you do not want DB, you may consider routing to ServiceBus topic https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c . Then you can create topic subscription per device with filter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters . And then finally your website can subscribe to specific subscription based on logged in user.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT can I do that filtering you have mentioned with Event Hubs. Because I have already done the routing to Events Hubs. Each user has an Event Hub with just his devices routed to it.

Comment: Per user event hub would be very costly

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT

I want to get ride of the Service Bus... How would you recommend me to read the data from the DB on real time from the client side. Im using Cosmos DB to store the data.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed